# default value assigned to an attribute of a function is not carrying it in php

Tags: php, null, default, user-defined-functions, is-empty

I have the below code in php.

```
 function something($abc='abc', $bcd){
        echo $abc;
        echo $bcd;
    }
something('','Hi buddy');
```

Output I am getting

```
Hi buddy
```

I understand why I am getting it so, It is because the value I have sent for `$abc` is empty.

Is there any way in php to get the default value if the value is set `empty, false, NULL, undefined`

I am sorry if it looks silly. Till today I had thought that the empty value will be replaced with the default value assigned in the function.

any suggestions. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the default results, you need to call your function like this:

```
something(null, 'Hi buddy');
```

'' is not an empty parameter, it's just an empty string.